# Applying SVM on a dataset

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, svm

I have written the following code to examine `svmtrain`.

```
a = 5*[randn(200, 1) + 5, randn(200, 1) + 5];
b = 5*[randn(200, 1) + 5, randn(200, 1) - 5];
all_data = [a;b];

plot(a(:,1) , a(:,2),'b.'); hold on
plot(b(:,1) , b(:,2),'r.');

group = ['r';'b'];

svmStruct = svmtrain(all_data, group,'ShowPlot',true);
```

I have created two normal distributed datasets (a and b) and then combined them into a single 2D array. Now I want to separate these two areas using  `svmtrain` but I don't know what should I do with the `Group` parameter. As matlab help stated I can use a 2x1 matrix of characters to imply the label of these two areas. I did so, But I don't know why my code is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should provide the class label for each instance. So use:

```
group = [repmat('r',200,1); repmat('g',200,1)];
svmStruct = svmtrain(all_data, group, 'ShowPlot',true);
```

[image: svm]